# How to add a space after fist character of string

Tags: php

I have a string named `$words = "Unbelievable`. 
I want the output to be `U nbelievable`

I tried this code:

```
implode(" ", str_split($words, 2))." ";
```

It's working but it affects on every 2 characters in the `string`.

I got this `Un be li ev ab le` using the code above.

I want only to add a space after first character in a `string`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or [substr_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) for this purpose. Try with either

```
$words = "Unbelievable";
echo substr($words, 0, 1) . ' ' . substr($words, 1);
```

or

```
echo substr_replace($words," ", 1, -strlen($words));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$words = "Unbelievable";
$str1 = substr($words, 0, 1); //set str1 to be Un
$str2 = substr($words, 1); //set str2 to be believable

$result = $str1." ".$str2; //result is 'Un believable'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $words = "Unbelievable".    
$word = substr_replace($words," ", 1, -strlen($words));
```